# How to make geolocation to be updated without refresh?

Tags: javascript

I want to make an application where you can see your geolocation(angularjs).I want to have this location updated every time without making a refresh on page.I've read something and i see i need to make a `watch` on location but i'm a little bit confused how to do this.I will apreciate any help or example.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It isn't very complicated.

```
watchCurrentPosition();
```

Here is a reference: https://www.codeofaninja.com/2013/08/navigator-geolocation-watchposition.html